# Calculation total Contribution based on total score and Grades

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have a scenario where calculation would need to be done based on the total scored runs and as per grade.
Below is the 2 players with their scores.

[image]

Below are the grade range that need to be applied .The total score is 115 and first player has the priority .So the calculation would be from 0-50,50-100 and 100-150.

[image]

So sachin would have 70 runs out of which 50 will be under grade 1 and the remaiing 20 in grade 2 .
Dhoni will start from 70 and fill withhis 30 out of 45 till 100 under grade 2.
After 100 ,the 15 left from Dhoni will be added to grade 3.

[image]

Looking for a query that does the calculation part based on the table date 1 and 2 .
Table 3 is the intended query output.

Comment: How do you decide to consider Sachin's runs first, and only then Dhoni's runs? You could have started with Dhoni and then followed with Sachin, and the output would be different. Also, when you explain your rule, explain also what must be done when there are ties. (For example, if you say "I start with Sachin since he scored more runs than Dhoni", then what is the rule if they had scored the same number of runs?) Also if anywhere in your answer you say "it doesn't matter, any order is fine", make sure that is in fact true and acceptable in the real-life problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ,i will update the details by addding another column that says priority.

Comment: Two more questions... First, what if the total is greater than 150? Shouldn't the last "grade" be unlimited range (101 to infinity)? In any case, if the total is greater than 150, what should be shown in the output? And second, do you have control over the structure of the tables? The `grades` table should only show the upper end of each range (50 - grade 1, 100 - grade 2, 150 (or `null` to indicate "unlimited") - grade 3, etc.)

Comment: I would say if greater than 150 use 4 .150-Inifinvity would be 4

Answer (score 0):

First let's set up the data. I start with three tables: `players` (one row per player; this includes an id, the name, and the priority - the priority shouldn't appear in the "scores" table); `grades` like in your question (although it **should** look more like the result of the `g` subquery I define in my `with` clause below); and `runs_scored`, showing for each match and each player how many runs they scored. **Important note** - there should also be a `matches` table (with match id and other details such as date, home team, visiting team etc.); I was lazy and just extracted match id's from the `runs_scored` table.

OK, so the data setup looks like this:

**CREATE OR RECREATE TABLES (DROP THEM FIRST IN CASE THEY EXIST ALREADY)**

```
drop table runs_scored purge;
drop table players     purge;
drop table grades      purge;

create table players (
  player_id number       primary key
, name      varchar2(20) not null
, priority  number       not null unique
);

create table grades (
  range     varchar2(20) primary key
, grade     number       not null unique
);

create table runs_scored (
  match_id  number not null -- references matches (should have that table too)
, player_id number references players
, score     number not null
, primary key (match_id, player_id)
);
```

**POPULATE THE TABLES**

```
insert into players
  select 1001, 'Sachin', 1 from dual union all
  select 1002, 'Dhoni' , 2 from dual union all
  select 1005, 'Ravi'  , 3 from dual
;

insert into grades
  select '0-50'   , 1 from dual union all
  select '50-100' , 2 from dual union all 
  select '100-150', 3 from dual
;

insert into runs_scored
  select 1, 1001,  70 from dual union all
  select 1, 1002,  45 from dual union all
  select 3, 1005,  50 from dual union all
  select 3, 1002,  50 from dual union all
  select 3, 1001,  50 from dual union all
  select 8, 1002, 160 from dual union all
  select 9, 1001,  40 from dual union all
  select 9, 1005,   0 from dual union all
  select 9, 1002,  15 from dual
;

commit;
```

Note that I assume that grades must be assigned separately for each match; if that is not the case, the query can be modified easily to apply the grades for total runs scored across all matches.

In the output I will exclude players who don't appear in the `runs_scored` table, as well as the odd ones that may appear with a score of 0 (and, presumably, shouldn't have been included in the first place). Of course, you could have a constraint to require the score to be > 0 in the first place.

Then here is one way to do this, taking extensive advantage of analytic functions:

**QUERY**

```
with
  g (runs, grade) as (
    select to_number(substr(range, instr(range, '-') + 1)), grade from grades
    union all
    select null, 1 + max(grade) from grades
  )
, matches (match_id) as (   -- there should be a MATCHES table; simulated here
    select distinct match_id from runs_scored
  )
, prep (match_id, player_id, name, priority, score, cumul_score, grade) as (
    select rs.match_id, rs.player_id, p.name, p.priority, rs.score,
           sum(rs.score) over (partition by rs.match_id order by p.priority),
           cast (null as number)
      from runs_scored rs join players p on rs.player_id = p.player_id
    union all
    select m.match_id, null, null, null, null, g.runs, g.grade
      from matches m cross join g
  )
, comps (match_id, cumul_score, player_id, name, score, grade) as (
    select match_id, cumul_score,
           last_value(player_id ignore nulls) over (partition by match_id
                                order by cumul_score desc, priority desc),
           last_value(name ignore nulls) over (partition by match_id
                                order by cumul_score desc, priority desc),
           cumul_score - lead(cumul_score, 1, 0) over (partition by match_id
                                order by cumul_score desc, priority desc),
           last_value(grade ignore nulls) over (partition by match_id
                                order by cumul_score desc, priority desc)
    from   prep p
  )
select match_id, player_id, name, score, grade, score * grade as final
from   comps
where  name is not null and score > 0
order  by match_id, cumul_score;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  MATCH_ID  PLAYER_ID NAME       SCORE GRADE      FINAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- ----------
         1       1001 Sachin        50     1         50
         1       1001 Sachin        20     2         40
         1       1002 Dhoni         30     2         60
         1       1002 Dhoni         15     3         45
         3       1001 Sachin        50     1         50
         3       1002 Dhoni         50     2        100
         3       1005 Ravi          50     3        150
         8       1002 Dhoni         50     1         50
         8       1002 Dhoni         50     2        100
         8       1002 Dhoni         50     3        150
         8       1002 Dhoni         10     4         40
         9       1001 Sachin        40     1         40
         9       1002 Dhoni         10     1         10
         9       1002 Dhoni          5     2         10
```

To understand how this works, it may help to break the code after each successive subquery in the `with` clause and to `select *` from that subquery. You will see what each step does.

Comment: Thanks for the kind help here,i will use the query and make some changes if needed and let you know .Have to say this is quite impressive and i would love to reach this stage.